# I'd like to parse kml feed from an URL to add the data into Mapbox

Tags: mapbox

is there a way to parse data from a kml RSS to add it into Mapbox? I have an Inreach device from Garmin and I'll go for a long trail in may. The idea is to create a cool map where family can follow me in real time. Problem is that garmin only give access to a kml feed via url where all the data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox maps support the display of real-time data, as demonstrated in [this Mapbox GL JS example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-geojson/). In this particular example, the position of the symbol on the map is being determined by the GeoJSON data obtained from the `url` (which serves periodically-updating GeoJSON).

As shown in the [Mapbox style specification](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/), a source object can be one of several types: `vector`, `raster`, `raster-dem`, `geojson`, `image`, or `video`. Given that you're working with KML, the best option would likely be to parse the KML feed periodically, convert the new data to GeoJSON, and pass it to a [GeoJSON source](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#geojson) as done in the example linked above.

If you're looking to display a line rather than a single point, [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-update-feature/) shows how you can update a line feature on your map in real time.